# How to deal with nullpointerexception in button view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.android.dermadetect.DoctorAdapter$1.onClick(DoctorAdapter.java:63)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you should check your xml file and java file. check this DoctorAdapter.java line 63

Comment: Please post what you have code and xml file

Comment: Absent a [mcve] with code that reproduces the problem, we can only point you to [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/3744182).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Were gonna need more than that. NullPointerException is probably the most commonplace exception in java.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try{
...
}
catch(NullPointerException e) {

}
```

Comment: Love it. General questions get general answers.